# Grid.GetRow and Grid.GetColumn keep returning 0

Tags: wpf, grid, row

I have a 10x10 `Grid`. And in each space I have added a label to which I added a mousedoubleclick event handler. So when I double click the label it's supposed to show the `Row` and `Column` number, but I only get 0 for both properties.

This is the code... (and yes I have set `Grid.SetRow` and `Grid.SetColumn` for each label)

```
private void grid_Checked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Grid.GetRow(e.Source as UIElement).ToString());
}
```

Comment: I have had this problem when adding controls programmatically from a C#, non-static class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that everything is hooked up correctly? The following works for me:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" MouseDown="Label_MouseDown">
        Label 0, 0
    </Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" MouseDown="Label_MouseDown">
        Label 0, 1
    </Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" MouseDown="Label_MouseDown">
        Label 0, 2
    </Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" MouseDown="Label_MouseDown">
        Label 1, 0
    </Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" MouseDown="Label_MouseDown">
        Label 1, 1
    </Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" MouseDown="Label_MouseDown">
        Label 1, 2
    </Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" MouseDown="Label_MouseDown">
        Label 2, 0
    </Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" MouseDown="Label_MouseDown">
        Label 2, 1
    </Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" MouseDown="Label_MouseDown">
        Label 2, 2
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
private void Label_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var label = e.Source as UIElement;
    var row = Grid.GetRow(label);
    var col = Grid.GetColumn(label);

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0},{1}", row, col));
}
```

The `MessageBox` contains the correct row and column when I click on one of the labels.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use [e.OriginalSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.originalsource.aspx) instead of e.Source.  The checked event, being a routed event, will change `e.Source` as it routes through the tree.

Comment: It's the same. Even though it's a routedEvent I catch it on the label. I know the name of the method isn't very well chosen. It's actually like this.
lbl.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(grid_Checked);

lbl being the label.